# Import Stata 15 output into Latex

Tags: tables, output

I know you may have seen this question dozens of times, but I still didn't find a helpful answer. I have to display some stata tables (descriptives, regressions, ...) in my uni research, but I don't know if there is a general way to do this. I do not have any command I can show you since I really don't know where to start from. I checked the `estout` command, but I should display the output exactly as it is in stata. I don't really want to do a screenshot of the output and import it in latex with `\includegraphics`.

I have a .dta stata file and I wrote the necessary codes in my .do file. I wonder if there is a package I can use to let latex read the stata codes. I read that I have to define the .dta file in latex and then type the .do file codes in latex to let him generate the appropriate output. Does anyone know how to do this?

Again, sorry for not providing any code.

Comment: since most of us won't have seen a stata data file you might at least show a small example file and describe what you want the typeset output to be (I assume it's some kind of text format, not binary data?)

Comment: the following link shows how data in Stata are organized: https://www.stata.com/features/overview/data-editor/ . Typing command in the To do file like `regress mathsc6 treated dadedr4 momedr4 relig famsize`, which is the multiple regression code. It then displays the following output in the .dta file: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/output/regression-analysis-2/

Answer (score 1):

Since STATA seems to be able to provide text output, use the `minted` or `listings` packages to display the content of the STATA file in your document, as it could be done for source code.

More specifically, with the `listings` package, do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{yourstatafile.extension}
\end{document}
```

See [this website](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings) for more information